# Compiler errors: undefined reference to `print'

Tags: c, compiler-errors

In my code I keep on getting these errors when trying to compile

> /tmp/ccshIakV.o: In function `main':
>
> project2.c:(.text+0x370): undefined reference to `print'
>
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

And this is my code

```
int main(void)
{
double a = 0;
double b = 0;
double c = 0;
double d = 0;
double e = 0;
double f = 0;
double g = 0;
double h = 0;
double i = 0;

char command = '\0';

printf("\n      Welcome\n");
printf("     Aquapodz Stress Analysis Program\n");
printf("    ==================================\n");
while (command != 'x');
    {
printf("\n\n(a), (b), or (c), enter trial data for vendor.\n(f)ail-rate,     (m)ean stress, (s)ummary, e(x)it\n");
printf("Please enter a command");
scanf("%c", &command);

if (command == 'a')
{
printf("Please enter stress values (GPa) for this trial.");
scanf("%lf", &a);
scanf("%lf", &b);
scanf("%lf", &c);
}
else if (command == 'b')
{
printf("Please enter stress values (GPa) for this trial.");
scanf("%lf", &d);
scanf("%lf", &e);
scanf("%lf", &f);
}
else if (command == 'c')
{
printf("Please enter stress values (GPa) for this trial.");
scanf("%lf", &g);
scanf("%lf", &h);
scanf("%lf", &i);
}
else if (command == 'f')
{

printf("Average failure rate:\nAzuview:%f\nBublon:%f\nCryztal:%f\n",        a+b+c, d+e+f, g+h+i);
}
else if (command == 'm')
{
printf("Average mean stress:\nAzuview:%f\nBublon:%f\nCryztal:%f\n",     a+b+c/3, d+e+f/3, g+h+i/3);
}
else if (command == 's')
{
print("Total (pass / fail) so far:\nAzuview:%f(%f/0)\nBublon:%f(%f/0)    \nCryztal:%f(%f/0)\n", a+b+c, a+b+c, d+e+f, d+e+f, g+h+i, g+h+i);
}
else if (command == 'x')
{

}
else
{
printf("Invalid Command! Please Try Again :)");
}

}
printf("Goodbye, Please Come Again!");
  return 0;
}
```

I have never encountered these errors before.

Comment: You have included header files right  in your  actual code ?

Comment: In general, the "undefined reference" error message typically means that you are using a function or variable for which there is no definition. For example, you include a header file which declares function foo, but forget to link the source/object file which implements foo when compiling.

Comment: "undefined reference to `print`" - Well, how about you change `print` to `printf`? The compiler couldn't have been more obvious than that!!!

Comment: yeah i just forgot to add it in for the post

Comment: @barakmanos The compiler isn't being "obvious" here at all but misses the error completely without appropriate warning settings. Implicit function declarations are an **indication** that something is wrong, but they are allowed. The error message here comes from the linker, so there's not even a line number. -> use compiler warnings, they would make it obvious.

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Yep, it is indeed a linkage error... Nevertheless, it remains just as obvious (with the exception of not being able to double-click it and jump to the corresponding line).

Answer (score 2):

```
else if (command == 's')
{
    print("Total (pass / fail) so far:\nAzuview:%f(%f/0)\nBublon:%f(%f/0)    \nCryztal:%f(%f/0)\n", a+b+c, a+b+c, d+e+f, d+e+f, g+h+i, g+h+i);
}
```

Just look at THIS part closely. To avoid such things, use compiler warnings (eg `-Wall -Wextra` for gcc) -- they warn about implicit function declaration in that case.

On a side note, regarding many other lines: no need for `printf()` if there is no data to be formatted. Use `puts()` instead (or `fputs()` to `stdout` if there should be no newline).

Comment: This is the best answer. You always need to compile at first with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` (asking for all warnings, extra warnings, and debugging information).

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code. You missed the `f` in `printf()` call.

You have to change

```
else if (command == 's')
{
print("Total (pass / fail) so far:\nAzuview:%f(%f/0)\nBublon:%f(%f/0)    \nCryztal:%f(%f/0)\n", a+b+c, a+b+c, d+e+f, d+e+f, g+h+i, g+h+i);
}
```

to

```
else if (command == 's')
{
printf("Total (pass / fail) so far:\nAzuview:%f(%f/0)\nBublon:%f(%f/0)    \nCryztal:%f(%f/0)\n", a+b+c, a+b+c, d+e+f, d+e+f, g+h+i, g+h+i);
     ^
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, I DON'T KNOW HOW I COULD BE SO STUPID!!!

Comment: @ThePixelPerson You're welcome. :-) (_Don't SHOUT , please_)

Comment: another quick question, when i run y program it asks for a command, and if u choose a, b, or c you are prompted to give it 3 values. my issue is, when i type in any command, it will run, and i can give them values, but my invalid command message will pop up, even though the process ran fine and was a valid command.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you need to use `printf` instead of just `print`

```
else if (command == 's')
{
print("Total (pass / fail) so far:\nAzuview:%f(%f/0)\nBublon:%f(%f/0)    \nCryztal:%f(%f/0)\n", a+b+c, a+b+c, d+e+f, d+e+f, g+h+i, g+h+i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 else if (command == 's')
 {

    print("Total (pass / fail) so far:\nAzuview:%f(%f/0)\nBublon:%f(%f/0)        \nCryztal:%f(%f/0)\n", a+b+c, a+b+c, d+e+f, d+e+f, g+h+i, g+h+i);
 }
```

In this line you typred  `print` instead of `printf`. Please correct it

Answer (score 0):

You missed a "f" to `printf`

```
else if (command == 's')
{
    print("Total (pass / fail) so far:\nAzuview:%f(%f/0)\nBublon:%f(%f/0) \nCryztal:%f(%f/0)\n", a+b+c, a+b+c, d+e+f, d+e+f, g+h+i, g+h+i);
}
```